# PostgreSQL DB freezes with large inserts

Tags: postgresql, performance, query-performance

I am developing a web application with an SQLAlchemy ORM linked with PostgreSQL database backend. I have this usecase where a client uploads a file of about 20 MB containing large data. What I am trying to do is,run a series of select, insert and update commands on about a million entries parsed from the uploaded file against the database.

I am on Ubuntu 12.0 with a 8 GB RAM, and whenever I perform this massive insert update operation, my memory hits about 90%  usage and freezes at about half way through the inserts and updates.

During this period, nothing gets inserted or updated. Nothing happens at all and unless I kill this process, it takes a toll on my system's performance.

I have 3 tables. Two contain data and the other one is a junction table containing the foreign keys of the first two tables, and a column specifying the number of rows inserted in the first two tables. I do NOT have indexes specified, and Autocommit is off.

I tried looking up bulk insertions and suggestions that said

> "COPY is better than INSERT" and "take your DB offline and insert" and
>   deferred Foreign key processings.

Please let me know if there are any ways to chunk my inserts so that I can serve other requests while the DB is occupied with writes. Else, my whole web application is frozen with this specific upload operation.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Cross post: http://stackoverflow.com/q/29799104/330315

Comment: So, there is no 12.0 version of Ubuntu, I guess it's 12.04.  Furthermore, something is really wrong there, 20 MB is not a big file (especially compared to 8 GBs of RAM).  What we need here is an output from `top` when this slowness happens, the resource-related settings from PostgreSQL, possibly relevant log entries from the slow periods.  And the PostgreSQL and kernel versions.

Comment: Are you sure Postgres is causing the memory usage growth?  Usually Postgres restrains itself to a small subset of memory (the `shared_buffers` setting)

Comment: Oh jeez. So I guess it is the ORM which is eating the RAM?

Comment: May I ask what the selects and updates are for, if the operation is actually an insert? Could you try to first insert all the rows, and then do the selects and updates? Also, do you really have to use an ORM for this task? It's just a wild guess, I have no experience with Postgres, but I had a similar problem once with SQL server.

Comment: Do you have any `AFTER` triggers? Deferred constraints? If not, it's highly likely that it won't be PostgreSQL its self using the RAM. Check `top`.

Comment: It may well be SQLAlchemy eating the RAM (it is a fairly heavy, although very feature-full ORM). There's a good entry in the FAQ on [bulk loading](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/faq/performance.html#i-m-inserting-400-000-rows-with-the-orm-and-it-s-really-slow). The recently released SQLAlchemy 1.0 includes new features for [bulk loading](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_0/orm/persistence_techniques.html#bulk-operations) which are considered "beta" quality at the moment, but may be useful for your case